# File Transfer using RDP Client

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003

Why can I copy & paste files via the clipboard between client and server when connected to Windows Server 2008 without having to share drives, but not with Windows Server 2003?

Comment: I refunded your bounty and closed this question as a duplicate. If you disagree with this, please flag this question for moderator attention or bring it up on [meta]. :)

Comment: A common limiting factor in this is if you're using an RDP gateway.

Comment: I'm not using RDP gateway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Advanced Clipboard Redirection* is a [feature of Windows Server 2008](https://serverfault.com/questions/74504/windows-server-2003-ts-versus-2008-r2-rds).

I didn't find a really good description of this feature, but [this blog post](http://clintboessen.blogspot.de/2009/07/windows-server-2008-terminal-services.html) states:

> The clipboard had been improved with Windows Server 2008 Terminal Services to enable stream support. This improves the performance of redirected drives, enable support for more types of data to be exchange via cut and paste e.g graphics, files, office data etc. I think this is fantastic I use it all the time - copying and pasting images in and out of RDP sessions.

It seems the copying&pasting of files via the clipboard required Server 2008, or (as you've determined) having shared drives.

Answer (score 2):

Edit the RDP connection, click the dropdown Options menu and go to the Local Resources tab. At the bottom click More...
Click the plus next to Drives and select which Local Drives you want to share with the remote connection.

Comment: Sharing a drive, indeed helped to make file copy-paste work, but on my other server (win 2008) file copy-paste works without any sharing, except clipboard.